# Правильно вывести предложение в echo

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подскажите в чем ошибка ? Хочу вывести через echo вот это предложение? но интерпритатор пишет ошибку Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in ...

Вот сама строчка

```
<div id='cover_container' style='background:url('cover_img/"$myrow['cover_img'];"');'>
```

P.s вывод начинался через echo "" (кавычки двойные)

Comment: экранируйте двойные кавычки с помощью \:

    echo "это \"текст\" с кавычками";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем там кавычки? Ты пытаешься парсить эту строку или это шаблон?

Если шаблон, то так:

```
<div id='cover_container' style='background:url('cover_img/<?php echo $myrow['cover_img']; ?>');'>
```

Если все же парсишь то так:

```
echo "<div id='cover_container' style='background:url('cover_img/$myrow['cover_img']');'>";
```

или так:

```
echo "<div id='cover_container' style='background:url('cover_img/".$myrow['cover_img']."');'>";
```

Из контекста приведенного вопроса не совсем понятно чего ты добиваешься от бедного echo ))